# Python: display matching keys to dictionary words

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I want to display the matching keys for the dictionary words in my project. My code currently outputs the keys but the **same** keys for whatever word you type in. For example, if i put `'england played well'` the keys returned will be `[737, 736, 735, 734, 733, 732, 731, 730, 729, 728]`. If i put `'Hello'` the **same** keys will be returned. Please see code below and let me know if i am doing anything wrong

```py
import re
import os
import math
import heapq

def readfile(path, docid):
    files = sorted(os.listdir(path))
    f = open(os.path.join(path, files[docid]), 'r',encoding='latin-1')
    s = f.read()
    f.close()
    return s

DELIM = '[ \n\t0123456789;:.,/\(\)\"\'-]+'

def tokenize(text):
    return re.split(DELIM, text.lower())

N = len(sorted(os.listdir('docs')))

def indextextfiles_RR(path):
    postings={}
    docLength = {}
    term_in_document = {}
    for docID in range(N):
        s = readfile(path, docID)
        words = tokenize(s)
        length = 0
        for w in words:
            if w!='':
                length += (math.log10(words.count(w)))**2
        docLength[docID] = math.sqrt(length)
        for w in words:
            if w!='':
                doc_length = math.log10(words.count(w))/docLength[docID]
                term_in_document.setdefault(doc_length, set()).add(docID)
                postings[w] = term_in_document
    return postings


def query_RR(postings, qtext):
    words = tokenize(qtext)
    doc_scores = {}
    for docID in range(N):
        score = 0
        for w in words:
            tf = words.count(w)
            df = len(postings[w])
            idf = math.log10(N / (df+1))
            query_weights = tf * idf
        for w in words:
            if w in postings:
                score = score + query_weights
        doc_scores[docID] = score
    res = heapq.nlargest(10, doc_scores)
    return res

postings = indextextfiles_RR('docs')
print(query_RR(postings, 'hello'))
```

When i run the postings, it should return hello and the list of keys associating with it.

Comment: Please see edited code

Comment: please see edits

Comment: I think I found the problem, try to print postings to see what you get. You are using the same `term_in_document` dictionary for every word in every file. I provided an answer with this issue and a set of useful tips to improve your code that I was applyign to try to understand what you were doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, your error comes from `term_in_document` as you are using the same dict for all the words in every file.

Several comments

1. `len(sorted(...))` its wasting resources sorting something (sorting is not cheap) that doesn't need to be sorted as you are only getting the length.
2. Reading files by number makes no sense at all, and to do this you end up calling the filesystem mutiple times to read the file names of the whole directory as you are listing the files each time you read one.
3. Files should be opened inside a `with` statement that handles closing the file for us.
4. Variables and functions should use `this_notation` while classes should use `ThisNotation`.
5. You are iterating twice over the words list just to get the decimal logarithms.

The logic afterwards is pretty confusing, you seem to be doing a RMS (Root Mean Square) of the decimal logarithm of the times each word appears but you don't divide it by the number of words. And afterward you get the logarithms again. You should probably define your problem better. I will edit my answer as I get new info.

```py
import re
import os
import math
import heapq

def read_file(path):
    with open(path, 'r', encoding='latin-1') as f:
        return f.read()

DELIM = '[ \n\t0123456789;:.,/\(\)\"\'-]+'

def tokenize(text):
    return re.split(DELIM, text.lower())

def index_text_files_rr(path):
    postings = {}
    doc_lengths = {}
    term_in_document = {}
    files = sorted(os.listdir(path))
    for i, file in enumerate(files):
        file_path = os.path.join(path, file)
        s = read_file(file_path)
        words = tokenize(s)
        length = 0
        # We will store pairs of the word with the decimal logarithm of
        # the word count here to use it later
        words_and_logs = []
        for word in words:
            # Discard empty words
            if word != '':
                # Compute the decimal logarithm of the word count
                log = math.log10(words.count(word))
                # Add the square of the decimal logarithm to the length
                length += log**2
                # Store the word and decimal logarithm pair
                words_and_logs.append((word, log))
        # Compute the square root of the sum of the squares
        # of the decimal logarithms of the words count
        doc_lengths[i] = math.sqrt(length)
        # Iterate over our stored pairs where we already have the
        # decimal logarithms computed so we do not have to do it again
        for word, log in words_and_logs:
            # No need to discard empty words here as we discarded them before
            # so words_and_logs will not have the empty word
            term_in_document.setdefault(log / doc_lengths[i], set()).add(i)
            postings[w] = term_in_document
    return postings


def query_rr(postings, qtext):
    words = tokenize(qtext)
    doc_scores = {}
    for i in range(N):
        score = 0
        for w in words:
            tf = words.count(w)
            df = len(postings[w])
            idf = math.log10(N / (df+1))
            query_weights = tf * idf
        for w in words:
            if w in postings:
                score = score + query_weights
        doc_scores[i] = score
    res = heapq.nlargest(10, doc_scores)
    return res

postings = index_text_files_rr('docs')
print(query_rr(postings, 'hello'))
```

Comment: I tried this however, i am still receiving the same issue ?, i also tried the '  with open(path, 'r', encoding='latin-1') as f:
        return f.read()' however it came up with an error saying   <ipython-input-24-22cc482f36c2> in readfile(path, docid)
      1 def readfile(path, docid):
----> 2      with open(path, 'r', encoding='latin-1') as f:
      3         return f.read()

IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'docs'

Comment: As I said, the answer is not complete. As stated in the first line, I think the error comes from having a single `term_in_document` dict for every word in every file. In the comment to your OP I asked if you could provide the output of `postings` so that I could confirm this (I can't do it myself as I don't have the file you are processing).

Comment: hi we managed to solve it, are you just able to explain the following section for me, its slightly confusing to me:   for word in words:
            if word != '':
                log = math.log10(words.count(word))
                length += log**2
                words_and_logs.append((word, log))
        doc_lengths[i] = math.sqrt(length)
        for word, log in words_and_logs:
            if word != '':
                term_in_document.setdefault(log / doc_lengths[i], set()).add(i)
                postings[w] = term_in_document
    return postings

Comment: @TheCodingKid I added comments to the code but the logic is the same you had in the OP. Bear in mind that if the sentence is something like `As soon as possible` you will store in `doc_lengths` the `square_root( log_10(2) ^ 2 + log_10(1) ^ 2 + log_10(2) ^ 2 + log_10(1) ^ 2 )`, this is, words that appear multiple times will be added to the length multiple times (this happens in your code, I didn't change this).